# PyQT5 Main window import syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, pyqt5

I have the following code saved down in a file called Main_Win.py which is from a PyQt5 design which is not supposed to be edited.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Main_Win.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1500, 700)
        MainWindow.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("monkey.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.display_data = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.display_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 1381, 361))
        self.display_data.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.display_data.setObjectName("display_data")
        self.pause_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pause_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 560, 131, 51))
        self.pause_button.setObjectName("pause_button")
        self.play_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.play_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 560, 131, 51))
        self.play_button.setObjectName("play_button")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1500, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuOptions = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuOptions.setObjectName("menuOptions")
        self.menuAbout = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAbout.setObjectName("menuAbout")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen_Learning_Package = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_Learning_Package.setObjectName("actionOpen_Learning_Package")
        self.actionExit_Ctrl_Q = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit_Ctrl_Q.setObjectName("actionExit_Ctrl_Q")
        self.actionChange_Font = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionChange_Font.setObjectName("actionChange_Font")
        self.actionChange_Font_Color = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionChange_Font_Color.setObjectName("actionChange_Font_Color")
        self.actionChange_Words_Per_Minute = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionChange_Words_Per_Minute.setObjectName("actionChange_Words_Per_Minute")
        self.actionCreate_Learning_Package = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionCreate_Learning_Package.setObjectName("actionCreate_Learning_Package")
        self.actionVersion_1_1 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionVersion_1_1.setObjectName("actionVersion_1_1")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen_Learning_Package)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit_Ctrl_Q)
        self.menuOptions.addAction(self.actionChange_Font)
        self.menuOptions.addAction(self.actionChange_Font_Color)
        self.menuOptions.addAction(self.actionChange_Words_Per_Minute)
        self.menuOptions.addAction(self.actionCreate_Learning_Package)
        self.menuAbout.addAction(self.actionVersion_1_1)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuOptions.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAbout.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ultra-Fast Conceptualizer"))
        self.display_data.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pause_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pause ||"))
        self.play_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Play "))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuOptions.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Options"))
        self.menuAbout.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))
        self.actionOpen_Learning_Package.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Learning Package"))
        self.actionExit_Ctrl_Q.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit (Ctrl+Q)"))
        self.actionChange_Font.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change Font"))
        self.actionChange_Font_Color.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change Font Color"))
        self.actionChange_Words_Per_Minute.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change Words Per Minute"))
        self.actionCreate_Learning_Package.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Create Learning Package"))
        self.actionVersion_1_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Version 1.1"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I then have my main application file where I am trying to import the PyQt5 file from. Code below

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from Main_Win import Ui_MainWindow



class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        #self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.play_button.clicked.connect(play_button_clicked)

        

    def play_button_clicked(self):

        print('woohoo this worked')
        sys.exit()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = qtw.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am now trying to call a button click to print a statement and exit the application but it doesn't seem that I am able to get this right. Is anyone able to help and explain to me what the right procedure for making this call should be?

Comment: Why did you comment out those two lines about `self.ui`?

Comment: Hi musicamante, I tried using both those statements but they seem to have no effect on whether or not the statement runs! Besides they are called in the main function at the bottom. Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **not** using your `MainWindow` class; in fact you're also *overwriting* that name (also note that variable names should *not* start with an uppercase letter, as only constants and classes should have capitalized names).

```
class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # note: the button is a member of self.ui
        self.ui.play_button.clicked.connect(play_button_clicked)

    def play_button_clicked(self):
        print('woohoo this worked')
        # you should not directly use sys.exit from a widget
        qtw.QApplication.quit()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that you could even use multiple inheritance:

```
class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # in this case, the button is a direct member of the class
        self.play_button.clicked.connect(play_button_clicked)
```

Learn more about proper usage of ui files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Awesome thanks heaps musicamante. What would be the more correct way of doing it? Using mulktiple inheritance as sated in your second example or using class inheritance as per your first example? Thanks for highlighting my bad mistakes :-) will avoid this in future!

Comment: As always, there's no *absolutely* correct way, and it depends on many reasons, including personal choices or habits. I normally prefer the multiple inheritance, as I believe that the `ui` object is often more of a pointless complication: the class it's built on is already a widget (hence, an UI object), so I see no benefit in separating the main class and the children by having an "intermediate" object to access all those elements, but that's *my* opinion. Also consider that you can also *directly* build the ui on an "empty" widget: just inherit from the base widget (QMainWindow in your case)

Comment: and then use `uic.loadUi("somefile.ui", self)` right after the `super().__init__()`, which works almost as the multiple inheritance method (you can directly access widgets with `self.someWidget`) but with the benefit of skipping the pyuic passage at all: you won't risk forgetting to regenerate the ui files after each modification, which often leads to unnecessary headaches. Just import the uic module along the others: `from PyQt5 import uic`.

Comment: Hmmm very interesting. I tried doing that and I totally think this would save me a ton of time and very very helpfulif I can get it to work. Could you provide a small example of how a widget could be referenced? This is the issue I am facing now when trying to set font on the text label called display_text using running this function def font_choice(self):

        self.display_data.setFont(QFontDialog.getFont(0, self.display_data.font()))

Comment: If the label is called `display_text`, then why are you referencing `self.display_data`?

Comment: sorry it's called display_data (it's a text label) thanks for your time, very much appreciate your knowledge on this subject!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236055/discussion-between-jo3dirt-and-musicamante).